# jquery appending an increment after the label

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="main_holder">
      <div class="input_holder">
        <label for="something">Email</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="field_input" name="email" /> 
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>

      <div class="input_holder">
        <label for="something">Address</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="field_input" name="address" /> 
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>

      <div class="input_holder">
        <label for="something">Name</label><br/>
            <input type="text"  id="field_input" name="name" /> 
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$('a.add').click( function() { 
        var n=$(this).prevAll('.input_holder').size()+1;
        $(this).prev('.input_holder').clone().insertBefore(this);
        $(this).prev('.input_holder').find('label').append(n);
        return false;
    });
```

So if my label's name is email the result after this is:

- 1st click: Email 2
- 2nd click: Email 23
- 3rd click: Email 234

The reason is doing this is because after every append it takes the previous which already has the number. So my problem right now is how to fix that so it only puts the number one time each

Result I want:

- 1st click: Email 2
- 2nd click: Email 3
- 3rd click: Email 4

Comment: What does your html look like? Can you post a JSFiddle? I'd suggest putting the count in a span, and simply updating the span's html with the new count, but I don't know if you can do that without the html.

Comment: Cheers, I've added an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a regular expression `.replace` instead:

```
$(this).prev('.input_holder').find('label').append('0').text( function(i,str) {
    return str.replace(/\d+$/, n);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="main_holder">
  <div class="input_holder">
    <label for="something">Email</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="field_input" name="email" /> 
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>

  <div class="input_holder">
    <label for="something">Address</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="field_input" name="address" /> 
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>

  <div class="input_holder">
    <label for="something">Name</label><br/>
    <input type="text"  id="field_input" name="name" /> 
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('a.add').click( function(e) { 
  var $this = $(this),
      $prev = $this.prevUntil('.add');

  $prev.last().clone().insertBefore(this);
  $this.prev('.input_holder').find('label').append($prev.length + 1);

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/4B3xU/

I've modified the JS, but not the html.

Here's what I've done:

1. You always clone the first input, so never get the number as well
2. Fixed a bug that would clone the Email input even if you wanted to add an Address input
3. Removed return false in favour of e.preventDefault();
4. Cached some selectors on click. Could do more but this should suffice.